# What is a succinct way to extract a range of elements in a Set (or a Map) in log n time?

Tags: haskell

I know that there's `split`, but it's really a mouthful to get a range using this function:

```
import qualified Data.Set as S

-- The lower bound is inclusive and the upper bound is exclusive.
range' :: Ord a => (a, a) -> S.Set a -> S.Set a
range' (lower, upper) s = 
    let (_, e, right) = S.splitMember lower s
        (left, _)     = S.split upper right
    in  if e
          then S.union (S.singleton lower) left
          else left

main :: IO ()
main = do
    print $ range' (0, 3) (S.fromList [-1,2,0,1,5,6,3,7])
    return ()

-- output:
--   fromList [0,1,2]
```

Is there a better way?

---

**Edit:** I guess what I'm really asking is, how come this function is not included in the package? I think it's both useful and natural to the abstraction. It's strange to me that I couldn't find such function in the package.

Comment: An observation: I can think of at least eight variants of this function off the top of my head. Perhaps it makes sense from a library design point of view to include all the pieces you need to make the variant that does just what you need -- as the current design does -- instead of trying to figure out all the variants anybody might ever need and including them all -- as you seem to be proposing.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `S.union (S.singleton lower)` you may just use [`insert`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.6.3/docs/Data-Set.html#v:insert).

Also, note that your code is buggy when `upper <= lower` because, when upper bound is exclusive, such intervals are empty and the out-put should be empty regardless, however your code returns `S.singleton lower` if `lower` is in the input set.

```
range' :: Ord a => (a, a) -> S.Set a -> S.Set a
range' (lower, upper) s
    | lower < upper = if inc then S.insert lower out else out
    | otherwise     = S.empty
    where (_, inc, out) = S.splitMember lower . fst $ S.split upper s
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you think it's a conscious choice that this function is not included in the package? Because I think it's both useful and natural to the abstraction.

Comment: @trVoldemort Ask to the package mainteiners. They are the only ones that can answer your question and their email should be found in the documentation of the package.